# help understanding the HR manager email

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, human-resources, helping

I am a recent graduate in search of jobs and giving interviews.
I gave my final onsite interview with a big Financial firm on Jan. 17, 2019 for a Software Developer role. On Jan. 25 I was told that the feedback from the interview is positive and I got a compensation call from them after a week, where I was told that they will extend an offer in a week but its been like three weeks and today I got this email from them:

```
 We are still hopeful that we will be able move forward but
do not have an exact timeline at this point. 
We are working on next steps still and will follow-up as soon as we have another update.
```

my questions are:

Does this infer that there is still a possibility that I dont get an offer?
What should my response be?
I was actually waiting for this job without applying to other companies. Should I start applying for other companies?

If this is not the right place to post this please guide me.
thank you.

Comment: Once I was in a process, and after 4-8 weeks, 2-3 interviews, setting an expected salary and received a relocation offer, they said to me that in the middle of the process, management decided to restructure the office and hire other roles, different from the one I applied. I applied for Software development, but they decide to reduce SD staff and hire QA. If you have different processes in parallel, then you could have the chance to choose the best offer for you.

Comment: Possibly not a wise move to use your real name. Even if you use an alias, the date might give you away. There first thought will be "why is he asking random strangers instead of us" and there second might possibly be "do we really want this guy, if he posts our emails on the internet?". I advise you to delete this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does this infer that there is still a possibility that I dont get an
>   offer?

Yes.  It is definitely possible you may or may not get the job. They might even probably still be interviewing other candidates and don't want to lose you as an option while a decision is made.  Hard to say.

> What should my response be?

A simple "thank you, I look forward to your response" type email should suffice.

> I was actually waiting for this job without applying to other
>   companies. Should I start applying for other companies?

You should have been doing that anyway.

Comment: Agreed. I'd say it's not a great sign when they initially seem to be ready to move forward, very specifically, and then vague, undefined issues delay moving forward. That usually means they are actively pursuing other options, but want to keep the person they have "hanging" just in case nothing else works out.

Comment: When my boss has had to send letters like this to people we interviewed and wanted to hire, it has generally been a question of whether we would even have that position to fill, not about who would fill it. I especially agree with the final point to this answer, which you might notice is in common with all three answers.

Answer (score 3):

You should *never* stop applying for jobs till you have a formal offer in hand.  There are many reasons why things can fall through even after a company seems interested in you.  In fact, after they truly are interested in you.  The market tanks, the company is in sales negotiation, the division might get cut, there is a hiring freeze..  you name it, it can happen.  And it needs not get as personal as the boss comes back from vacation and hates your resume. No amount of expressed enthusiasm can compensate for the lack of a signed contract.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this infer that there is still a possibility that I dont get an
>   offer?

Yes, there's still a possibility.

They are hopeful. But they don't have a timeline. That timeline could still be never.

> What should my response be?

You should thank them. You should then wait to hear from them while you continue to interview elsewhere.

> Should I start applying for other companies?

Yes. Start now if you have't already done so.

It's not over, until it's over.